# JIRA RestAPI createIssue with attachments RestException: 400 Bad Request:

Tags: java, jira-rest-java-api

I am trying to create a JIRA issue with Attachments using java api.

```
List<File> fList = new ArrayList<>();
newIssue = jira.createIssue(jiraconfig.issue.projectname, jiraconfig.issue.type)
                    .field(Field.ATTACHMENT, fList)
                    .field(Field.ASSIGNEE, jiraconfig.issue.assignee)
                    .execute();
```

But when the code executes, I am getting the below error.

```
Caused by RestException: 400 Bad Request: {"errorMessages":[],"errors":{"attachment":"Field does not support update 'attachment'"}}
->>  160 | request                        in net.rcarz.jiraclient.RestClient
```

When I remove the attachment part and execute the code, it executes fine.

I have also tried to create an empty issue first, and then later add the attachments to the issue using the following. And it is working with that.

```
//file is File object
newIssue.addAttachment(file)
```

But I do not want to fire an additional webservice call for each attachment. Is there a way to add the attachment directly while Creating the issue, instead of adding it after creating the issue?

Please suggest.

Comment: i am running into the same problem. Have you figured out the solution? How do I atleast add an attachment to an existing issue? Please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: No, I am going with the alternate approach for now. I create an issue without attachment first, and then attaching files one by one.

Comment: If you want to add attachment to an existing issue, then there is a method addAttachment(File) available on Issue class.